# Can I call constructor from another constructor (as a regular method)?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have 2 constructors.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass()
   {
     int id = 0;
     //Same behaviour
   }
   Public MyClass(int id)
   {
     //Same behaviour
   }
}
```

Both constructions implement the same behavior. The only difference is that, if the first constructor is called and the value of id = 0;

My question is to know if I can call the second constructor, instead of implemetanting the same behavior? If that's possible, do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called constructor chaining. It's achieved like so:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() : this(0) { }
    public MyClass(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Note that you can chain to the base-class constructor like so:

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass {
    public MyClass() : this(0) { }
    public MyClass(int id) : base(id) { }
}

public class MyBaseClass {
    public MyBaseClass(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

If there is a base class and you don't specify a constructor to chain to, the default is the accessible parameterless constructor, if there is one. If you do not specify a constructor to chain to and there is no accessible parameterless constructor, you will get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() : this(0) {
    }
    public MyClass(int id) {
    }
}
```

Here's [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173115.aspx) on it. (you have to scroll down a bit; try searching for `: this`)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass() : this(0)
   {
   }
   public MyClass(int id)
   {
     //Same behaviour
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is C# 4, an alternative is to use a default value for the constructor parameter (effectively making it *optional*):

```
public MyClass(int id = 0) { ...
```

I think this is the ideal solution for your example.

But it depends on whether you'd like to use this class as a type argument for a type parameter with a constructor constraint...

Answer (score 0):

Why not put this same behavior in a private function?

Comment: Why not chain constructors?